# Array within a struct and initialization

Tags: c, struct

Can anyone please help me identify what I'm doing wrong here?

I have the following struct:

```
typedef struct cell {
    int number;
    int marked[10];
    int crossed[10];
    struct cell *next_sibling;
}cell;
```

I'm getting an error:

> Expected expression before {

On the two lines below where I tried to initialize the arrays defined within the struct:

```
cell grid[10][10];

int main (){
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int c;
    while (getchar() != EOF){
        grid[i][j].number = c - '0';
        grid[i][j].marked = {0};
        grid[i][j].crossed = {0};
        ... and so on
    }

}
```

I'm normally able to initialize an empty array. But when it is defined in struct, I'm having difficulty doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing here isn't initialization, it's assignment, but you don't need to initialize it.  Global variables in C are automatically zero-initialized.  Just fill in the `number` fields if that's all you have to do.  If you *do* have to do something to the `marked` and `crossed` fields, use `bzero` or `memset`:

```
bzero(grid[i][j].marked, sizeof grid[i][j].marked);
memset(grid[i][j].marked, 0, sizeof grid[i][j],marked);
```

If you want to assign a specific value, you can certainly do that too:

```
grid[i][j].marked[3] = 17;
```

Comment: I still can't initialise it this way. I'll edit my post to show the whole code may be it will assist in understanding what I'm trying to do.

Comment: what if I want to initialise marked[] and crossed[] to someother values other than 0? Can I do that within the struct definition, or during the cell's initialisation?

Comment: Well, you can only *initialize* them at the definition, but you can assign values to their contents when configuring a given cell, yes.  Answer updated with a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

grid[0][0] refers to an instance of cell, not either of the arrays in cell.  You are only allowed to initialize arrays at declaration, so the best you can do is

cell grid[10][10] = {0};

In C++, structs can have constructors--the only difference between structs and classes is default visibility (private for classes, public for structs).

Comment: That doesn't work, I'm getting an error "Missing braces around initializer"

Comment: That initialization is valid C.  Your error is because you have some extra warnings turned on, which is commendable.  I don't think you'll want to go down the path of completely initializing this data structure if you can avoid it, though.  It's going to be a lot of code.